# Trying to Install on MAC OS Lion and getting Python error message

Tags: qgis, gdal, installation

Brand new to this and struggling to install QGIS on MAC OS X with Lion, I am not a techy - but noticed in the install read me that /usr/bin needs to be added to the GDAL.frameworks path.
Failing to see how and where to add this?
Full error message attached - any advice greatly appreciated and thanks for your time in advance
*Couldn't load plugin GdalTools due an error when calling its classFactory() method*

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 138, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/GdalTools/**init**.py", line 32, in classFactory
    from GdalTools import GdalTools
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 283, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/GdalTools/GdalTools.py", line 39, in 
    raise ImportError( error_str )
ImportError: No module named osgeo [python-gdal]

Python version:
2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)]

QGIS version:
1.7.4-Wroclaw Wroclaw,

Python path: ['/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python', '/Users/Rupert/.qgis/python', '/Users/Rupert/.qgis/python/plugins', '/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins/fTools/tools']

Answer (score 2):

it is a common bug, you can get info [here](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4288).

for installing qgis for mac os x, you can use Mac OS X installers for QGIS [here](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis).

> QGIS Standard
>
> Requirements:
>
> GDAL Complete 1.9 framework package
>
> GSL framework
>
> Optional:
>
> GRASS 6.4.2 Python Modules for plugins

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Thanks - think i'll load on to laptop which thankfully we did not load Lion onto. Appreciate your getting back to me.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found here:
[GDAL install on Mac: pip doesn't see gdal.h](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221770/gdal-install-on-mac-pip-doesnt-see-gdal-h/221785)

Essentially, there is an error in the gdal-py2.7.pth file in the latest version of GDAL. The best way to correct it is to compile the GDAL bindings using the special commands provided in the thread.