# GDAL install on Mac: pip doesn't see gdal.h

Tags: gdal, installation, mac

I'm trying to install GDAL on a Mac (macos 10.12.2). I downloaded the GDAL 2.1 Complete package from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks (which installs GDAL 2.1.2), and successfully ran the installer. Now I'm trying to compile the Python bindings, using `pip`. In my bash_profile, I added lines for include paths (where the GDAL installer put them):

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/Headers
export C_INCLUDE_PATH==/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/Headers
export LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/unix/lib
```

then I tried to compile the bindings with:

```
pip install gdal==2.1.2
```

but pip complained it could only find versions up to 2.1.0 ("No matching distribution found for gdal==2.1.2"). So I tried using 2.1.0 for the install:

```
pip install gdal==2.1.0
```

which got pip to attempt the install, but which eventually failed with:

```
fatal error: 'gdal.h' file not found
  #include "gdal.h"
       ^
 2 warnings and 1 error generated.
 error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Yet, the file gdal.h is located in the Header directory I set for my include paths.

I tried the advice given in the following questions:

[Python GDAL package missing header file when installing via pip](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28966/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip?rq=1)

[Install GDAL python package in virtualenv on mac](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198425/install-gdal-python-package-in-virtualenv-on-mac?noredirect=1&lq=1)

but it did not fix my problem.

What should I do next?

Comment: According to your link, the GDAL framework includes the python bindings. So why try to install them separately via pip?

Comment: I'm following **Westra 2016** [link](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/python-geospatial-development-third-edition), which says binding is a separate step in the installation process. Also, when I tried to import the `osgeo` module (part of GDAL complete), the shell reported it as not found, which seemed to confirm that it was not bound to Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Luke says, the Python bindings are included in the GDAL Framework (you can use 
[Suspicious Package](http://www.mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/), free, or [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com/), shareware, to examine the content of the GDAL 2.1 Complete package)

[image]

And there is gdal-py2.7.pth path file witch is installed in a in the Apple Python site-packages folder and points to the precedent folder (/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gdal-py2.7.pth)

[image]

But there is a problem: the content of this file is

```
import sys; sys.path.insert(0,'/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/Python/2.7/site-packages')
```

though it should be

```
import sys; sys.path.insert(0,'/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/Python/2.7/site-packages')
```

Therefore, simply correct the gdal-py2.7.pth file.

Now if you want to compile yourself the Python bindings, download the [GDAL 2.1.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/2.1.0) python module and

```
python setup.py build_ext -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/Headers -L/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/unix/lib -lgdal
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```